# XWayland not in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wayland, ppa

I am trying to get Wayland to run on Ubuntu 14.04. I found a webpage that has step by step install PPA and then do this next steps, but it is not working. I am trying to get it to working in VBox Client, so I can write in C to see if I can port a forked app I did for X and ImLib2 to Wayland. I have not gotten as far as looking into ImLib2 and Wayland yet. But still would like to get Wayland running on this VBox Client

these are the two web pages I am working off of so far.

[Wayland/ProgrammingClient](https://jan.newmarch.name/Wayland/ProgrammingClient/)

How to [Install Latest Wayland](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/04/latest-wayland-ubuntu-14-04-ppa/) in Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome via PPA

I switched WM to IceWm too - because I don't like Gnome not that this stops the installing of Wayland.

Anyone know how to get Wayland running on Ubuntu?

```
userd@userx-VirtualBox:~$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:wayland.admin/daily-builds
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp5n7rk34c/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp5n7rk34c/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key C95588B6 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp5n7rk34c/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key C95588B6: public key "Launchpad PPA for Wayland Administrators" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
userd@userx-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install weston xwayland
```

Then I get this error, telling me it is not in repo:

```
Package 'xwayland' has no installation candidate
```

It has these two in the repo I still have no idea what to install which one, if any one of them:

```
xwayland-lts-utopic - Xwayland X server

xwayland-lts-vivid - Xwayland X server
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a version of Wayland in that repo that's compatible with 14.04 Trusty Tahr. There are only versions for utopic, vivid, wily, xenial. You may have to upgrade to try Wayland.